# ERROR: python3-venv is not installed, aborting... (MacOS, Intel)

Tags: python, macos, terminal, stable-diffusion, webui

I want to warn you in advance, I am not in perfect command of the English language, but I will try to describe the problem and all its nuances as thoroughly and accurately as possible.

Just an hour ago I had the idea to download a stable diffusion web interface AUTOMATIC111111 on my iMac 2017 Ventura 13.5.2 (Intel), referring to this article: (https://aituts.com/stable-diffusion-mac-m1/)
By the way I already had homebrew and python 3.11.5 installed.

I did everything based on that article, but when I ran the command in terminal ./webui.sh I saw this: ERROR: python3-venv is not installed, aborting...
But when I entered the pip list command, the virtualenv folder showed up in the list

Comment: virtualenv is not venv : https://pythonhow.com/what/what-is-the-difference-between-venv-pyvenv-pyenv-virtualenv-virtualenvwrapper-pipenv/#:~:text=In%20summary%2C%20venv%20and%20virtualenv,Python%20versions%20on%20your%20machine.